# Searching array for specific token/string C

Tags: c, arrays, search, token

this is my code where I'm really stuck right now.
The thing is, the user enters a Morse code then store each on an array by tokenizing it, now my problem is, how would I search the array where I stored each token for a specific string?

For example I entered : `.... . .-.. .-.. --- / .-- --- .-. .-.. -..` as my Morse code which would then be tokenized.

Now I want to search each tokens in the array for a specific string for example:

I'll search for "...." then if it searches one, it would print out H, and so on until it forms the word.

Same goes for all letters and numbers in the alphabet.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    #define LIMIT 200
    int main(){
       char morse[LIMIT],*decoded[300];
       char *token;
       int i=0,c;

       printf("Enter morse code: ");
       gets(morse);

       token = strtok(morse, " ");

       while( token != NULL){

        //printf("%s\n",token);
        //strcpy(decoded[i],token);

        decoded[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

       }

       if(strcmp(decoded[i],"....")==0){
        printf("HELLO");
       };   
       //for(i=0;i<sizeof(decoded);i++){ 
       //   printf("%s\n",decoded[i]);
       //} 

       system("pause");
       return 0;
    }
```

EDIT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LIMIT 200
int main(){
char morse[LIMIT],*temp[300],decoded[LIMIT];
char *token;
int i=0,c;

printf("Enter morse code: ");
gets(morse);

token = strtok(morse, " ");

while( token != NULL){

    //printf("%s\n",token);
    //strcpy(temp[i],token);

    temp[i++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

}

for(i=0;temp[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(strstr(temp[i],".-")){
    printf("A");
} else if(strstr(temp[i],"-...")){
    printf("B");
}else if(strstr(temp[i],"-.-.")){
    printf("C");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-..")){
    printf("D");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".")){
    printf("E");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"..-.")){
    printf("F");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"--.")){
    printf("G");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"....")){
    printf("H");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"..")){
    printf("I");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".---")){
    printf("J");
 }
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-.-")){
    printf("K");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".-..")){
    printf("L");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"--")){
    printf("M");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-.")){
    printf("N");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"---")){
    printf("O");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".--.")){
    printf("P");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"--.-")){
    printf("Q");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".-.")){
    printf("R");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"...")){
    printf("S");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-")){
    printf("T");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"..-")){
    printf("U");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"...-")){
    printf("V");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],".--")){
    printf("W"); 
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-..-")){
    printf("X");
} 
else if(strstr(temp[i],"-.--")){
    printf("Y");
}
else if(strstr(temp[i],"--..")){
    printf("Z");
}else if(strstr(temp[i],"/")){
    printf(" ");

}else{
printf("ERROR");
}
//printf("%s",strstr(temp[i],"...."));
}

   //for(i=0;i<sizeof(temp);i++){
   //    printf("%s\n",temp[i]);
   //}      

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your second block of code, you need to use either an array of a structure type or two parallel arrays if you've not learned about structures so that you don't write out almost the same code 27 times. If you've tokenized properly, you should be using `strcmp()` and not `strstr()`; you want to print the letter that exactly matches the string, as otherwise, every letter after E that contains a dot is presented as an E (fortunately, T is near the end of the alphabet, but the Morse code for each of the letters U-Z contains a dash, and would be treated as T).

Comment: You also don't assign `temp[i] = NULL;` after the `strtok()` loop so your next loop is not guaranteed to terminate in a timely manner. In fact, you could use a loop such as `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)` instead of `for (i = 0; temp[i] != NULL; i++)` since `i` contains the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

try this `--->`

1. Can use `strstr` to find substring.
2. Initialize a count index to find the position,

Comment: it worked! now all I need is fixing this runtime error which is caused by the for loop.

Comment: Glad could help. `--->`Should check the `count` value.

Comment: Got a new problem thou, it has problems in recognizing codes with the same pattern style.

for example, M is --- and O is --

if I wrote -- it still prints out M

Comment: ok. Break the string into `---` , `--` etc. Then use `strcmp` to compare the equivalent characters. 

##`strpbrk` is also worth looking into

Comment: I don't get what you meant, can u give me an example? using my code?

Comment: something like 

`strcmp(decodeed[i], "---") {printf("M");}`








`strcmp(decodeed[i], "--") {printf("O");}`

Comment: check my  post, I edited it and added the code so you can check it

Comment: it worked, but after outputting the result, a runtime error occurs, must be from the for(i=0;temp[i]!='\0\;i++)

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIMIT 200

int main(void)
{
    char morse[LIMIT];
    char *temp[LIMIT];
    char *token;
    char *str;
    int i = 0, j;
    struct Morse { char code[8]; char letter; };
    struct Morse alphabet[] =
    {
        { ".-",   'A' },
        { "-...", 'B' },
        { "-.-.", 'C' },
        { "-..",  'D' },
        { ".",    'E' },
        { "..-.", 'F' },
        { "--.",  'G' },
        { "....", 'H' },
        { "..",   'I' },
        { ".---", 'J' },
        { "-.-",  'K' },
        { ".-..", 'L' },
        { "--",   'M' },
        { "-.",   'N' },
        { "---",  'O' },
        { ".--.", 'P' },
        { "--.-", 'Q' },
        { ".-.",  'R' },
        { "...",  'S' },
        { "-",    'T' },
        { "..-",  'U' },
        { "...-", 'V' },
        { ".--",  'W' },
        { "-..-", 'X' },
        { "-.--", 'Y' },
        { "--..", 'Z' },
        { "/",    ' ' },
    };
    enum { NUM_MORSE = sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(alphabet[0]) };

    printf("Enter morse code: ");
    if (fgets(morse, sizeof(morse), stdin) == 0)
        return 0;
    if ((token = strchr(morse, '\n')) != NULL)
        *token = '\0';

    str = morse;
    while ((token = strtok(str, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        temp[i++] = token;
        //printf("%s\n", token);
        str = NULL;
    }
    temp[i] = NULL;

    for (i = 0; temp[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        //printf("%-6s ", temp[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_MORSE; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(temp[i], alphabet[j].code) == 0)
            {
                putchar(alphabet[j].letter);
                break;
            }
        }
        //putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
Enter morse code: .... . .-.. .-.. --- / .-- --- .-. .-.. -..
HELLO WORLD
```

You could improve on the linear search if you wanted to, but it probably isn't worth it. One option would be to sort in order of frequency in which the letters appear in normal English (so E comes before T, etc); another is to sort and use binary search.